# Using PHP, how can I add quotations to a non-standard INI file?

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I'm having to work with a custom application that stores information in an INI formatted file.

Unfortunately, it doesn't use double-quotes around all the values, so PHP's `parse_ini_file` function won't work.

Is there some way to add quotations around ALL the values in the INI file so that the `parse_ini_file` would be able to parse it?

Comment: I believe sample data is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something that works for me!

```
$lines = file_get_contents('bravo.txt');

$search = array("=", "\r\n");
$replace = array("=\"", "\" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = preg_replace('^([^=]+)=\s*(.*)$', '$1="$2"", $fileContent);
```

This should make sure you are not falsely including whitespaces in your values.